# How to reset warnings completely

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, warnings

How can I see a warning again without restarting python. Now I see them only once.

Consider this code for example:

```
import pandas as pd  
pd.Series([1]) / 0
```

I get

```
RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in true_divide
```

But when I run it again it executes silently.

**How can I see the warning again without restarting python?**

---

I have tried to do

```
del __warningregistry__
```

but that doesn't help.

Seems like only some types of warnings are stored there.
For example if I do:

```
def f():   
    X = pd.DataFrame(dict(a=[1,2,3],b=[4,5,6]))
    Y = X.iloc[:2]
    Y['c'] = 8
```

then this will raise warning only first time when `f()` is called. 
However, now when if do `del __warningregistry__` I can see the warning again.

---

What is the difference between first and second warning? Why only the second one is stored in this `__warningregistry__`? Where is the first one stored?

Comment: does `import warnings
warnings.resetwarnings()` work?

Comment: Nope. It doesn't even help for the second example. :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How can I see the warning again without restarting python?

As long as you do the following at the beginning of your script, you will not need to restart.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import warnings
np.seterr(all='warn')
warnings.simplefilter("always")
```

At this point every time you attempt to divide by zero, it will display

```
RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in true_divide
```

---

Explanation:

We are setting up a couple warning filters. The first ([`np.seterr`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.seterr.html)) is telling NumPy how it should handle warnings. I have set it to show warnings on *all*, but if you are only interested in seeing the Divide by zero warnings, change the parameter from `all` to `divide`.

Next we change how we want the `warnings` module to always display warnings. We do this by setting up a [warning filter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/warnings.html#the-warnings-filter).

> What is the difference between first and second warning? Why only the second one is stored in this __warningregistry__? Where is the first one stored?

This is described in the [bug report](https://bugs.python.org/msg75117) reporting this issue:

> If you didn't raise the warning before using the simple filter, this
>   would have worked. The undesired behavior is because of
>   __warningsregistry__. It is set the first time the warning is emitted.
>   When the second warning comes through, the filter isn't even looked at.
>   I think the best way to fix this is to invalidate __warningsregistry__
>   when a filter is used. It would probably be best to store warnings data
>   in a global then instead of on the module, so it is easy to invalidate.

Incidentally, the [bug](https://bugs.python.org/issue4180) has been closed as fixed for versions 3.4 and 3.5.

Comment: Thanks this does work. I just have to remember to specify that before I run anything else. If I get even one warning before then everything is hopeless.

Answer (score 0):

`warnings` is a pretty awesome standard library module. You're going to enjoy getting to know it :)

### A little background

The default behavior of `warnings` is to only show a particular warning, coming from a particular line, on its first occurrence. For instance, the following code will result in two warnings shown to the user:

```py
import numpy as np

# 10 warnings, but only the first copy will be shown
for i in range(10):
    np.true_divide(1, 0)

# This is on a separate line from the other "copies", so its warning will show
np.true_divide(1, 0)
```

You have a few options to change this behavior.

### Option 1: Reset the warnings registry

when you want python to "forget" what warnings you've seen before, you can use [`resetwarnings`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html#warnings.resetwarnings):

```py
# warns every time, because the warnings registry has been reset
for i in range(10):
    warnings.resetwarnings()
    np.true_divide(1, 0)
```

Note that this also resets any warning configuration changes you've made. Which brings me to...

### Option 2: Change the warnings configuration

The [warnings module documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html) covers this in greater detail, but one straightforward option is just to use a `simplefilter` to change that default behavior.

```py
import warnings
import numpy as np

# Show all warnings
warnings.simplefilter('always')
for i in range(10):
    # Now this will warn every loop
    np.true_divide(1, 0)
```

Since this is a global configuration change, it has global effects which you'll likely want to avoid (all warnings anywhere in your application will show every time). A less drastic option is to use the context manager:

```py
with warnings.catch_warnings():
    warnings.simplefilter('always')
    for i in range(10):
        # This will warn every loop
        np.true_divide(1, 0)

# Back to normal behavior: only warn once
for i in range(10):
    np.true_divide(1, 0)
```

There are also more granular options for changing the configuration on specific types of warnings. For that, check out the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html#overriding-the-default-filter).